# follow path, CTRL P, not work

Tags: bezier-curves, parent

I am trying to do a "follow path" but when I go to the: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>. That option doesn't show up. 
I look the center of the objects and them are equal.

Also, I tried to link the object in the "follow path" but I can't select the curve.

My version is: v2.78

Comment: Select the object first, then press and hold **Shift** while selecting the curve (so that both of them are selected, but the curve is the "active" object) Then use Ctrl P. Also for alternative way to make an object follow a path you can use a **follow path** constraint

Comment: Like I said, I tried but when I make this, what show up is: set parent to. object, object(keep ...), vertex, vertex(triangle).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You chose circle from the mesh category. on the left side (or using Shift-A in the scene window) go to create and then to curve and now the select circle.(The function of this circle is different from the one you choose from mesh category)

Comment: @Timoteo: Moujan thinks you're using a mesh object for a path. You need to use a CURVE for a path. A curve is a different type of object you can place in your scene, and is NOT a group of connected vertices. Is Moujan right?